# Containers for a Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, containers

I would like to take a doubt about the container to run a "Spring Application", in my opinion one of many features who Spring Framework offer is a possibility to create application without container EE. Is right use this type of container ("WildFly", "GlassFish")  with a spring project ? In my option is wrong but i'm open to listening more people.

i saw a article where the author are showing the features of Spring 4 with the WildFly, but i didn't  agree, so i would like to take more opinions about this topic here.

Comment: Yes, you can create a non-EE container using Spring.  Yes, you can use Spring in an EE application server.  Do either of those sentences answer your question?

Comment: What does not make sense to me is why use them? An EE contaner today come with many features that you do not always use them in your application, but when you boot your application all the features will be initialized even if you are not using and this is a waste of resource as the production environment. And that's one of the things that I see as an advantage in making an application with Spring because I have the ability to configure just what I'll use.

Comment: That's a different question.  Personally, I would use them because Spring is better designed than pre-annotation-drive application servers.  Spring is less useful now, with new annotation-driven servers, which learned a lot from Spring.  But that's not really a question for SO.  Unless you phrase it for your specific case.

Comment: I think the answer is 'It depends on what you are doing".  If you need some JEE components like EJBs that you need a 'container' but if you are doing straight servlet programming with Spring, then you don't really need a EE container.

Comment: Yes mike perfect i agree with you. That's what I was wanting to confirm my point of view was correct, I still see many people doing this kind of confusion.

Comment: I guess this is a rather "opinion-based" question, without more constraints or precisions about the targeted uses case. Spring can handle both EE containers and lightweight containers, whatever works best for your application, hosting infrastructure, company policy, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Spring Web and Web MVC you will typically use a lightweight container like Tomcat, Jetty or any other servlet container - maybe embedded like Spring Boot does.

Spring Web is designed to work without a full JEE container but will also work deployed inside one.

With Spring without JEE you have much more control about the features you use. A full appserver has a bundled feature list, you get all or none. Spring offers you to pick what you need resulting in a more slim application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all it is a little tricky to say that "something" is wrong or right in software development, mainly in this type of subjective question. As always, that really depends on what you need and on the EE Container that that you are using.

Let's get Widlfly as example. Since JBoss 7 (and now Wildfly) I do not think we can say that JBoss is a "heavy" Server, as it starts in just a few seconds, much faster than in the earlier versions. While it is true that Wildfly comes with a lot of services that you may not use, it is not correct to say that you get "all or none", for at least 2 reasons:

- You can disable the services you do not need.
- Wildfly works with the concept of lazy-loading for its services, which means that it will only load the services that are required to run a given application.

Having said that, we can not forget that Spring also uses some EE services, if you want to. So, if you need to use Spring with JMS, for example, you still need a JMS container. In this case, you can use an EE Server without needing to install additional services or you can start a JMS container in your Tomcat.

Besides the EE features, there is also the question of features related to the server, such as configurability/manageability (Web interface, CLI), HA, scalability... that really varies from server to server and I think Jboss 7/Widfly does a good work on these points.

Comment: Even after seeing all your points, still do not see a real approach to this type of container with spring applications, I will use the example you have told "JMS", if we see the default implementation and recommends by spring still to RabbitMQ which has a complete and updated integration of the new JMS features (http://goo.gl/WDrSKl). The WildFly has integration with HornetMQ where can't forget to mention has a huge potential, but their integration is not updated.

Comment: Two other points that can not fail to mention here is that I'll be becoming a hostage of this container and volume of required feature is sure to be bigger than the tomcat or jetty. Let's consider this case: Spring.io serves Their 500k users 24 × 7 with 4x2GB app instances. (http://goo.gl/jc08SD)
In your opinion what would be the required configuration to simulate this environment with the WildFly?

Comment: I as a developer I need to think about all the factors of the life cycle of an application and the production environment is one of them.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, for this reason I opened this topic to see more opinions.

Comment: 1. I can't see your point here. The link you posted shows improvements to Spring JMS integration, it has no relation to RabbitMQ/AMQP. It still assumes there is a JMS container (I am not sure RabbitMQ does that).
2. Humm..Maybe here you going to the wrong way. I think this is more related to how your application is structured and coded than to the web/app server(s) that it is deployed.